# What's the best way to convert non-generic collection to a generic collection?

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-objects

I've been teaching myself LINQ recently and applying it to various little puzzles. However, one of the problems I have run into is that LINQ-to-objects only works on generic collections. Is there a secret trick/ best practice for converting a non-generic collection to a generic collection?

My current implementation copies the non-generic collection to an array then operates on that, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

```
public static int maxSequence(string str)
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, "H+|T+");
    Match[] matchArr = new Match[matches.Count];
    matches.CopyTo(matchArr, 0);
    return matchArr
        .Select(match => match.Value.Length)
        .OrderByDescending(len => len)
        .First();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way is usually the [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method:

```
IEnumerable<Match> strongMatches = matches.Cast<Match>();
```

Note that this is deferred and streams its data, so you don't have a full "collection" as such - but it's a perfectly fine data source for LINQ queries.

`Cast` is automatically called if you specify a type for the range variable in a query expression:

So to convert your query completely:

```
public static int MaxSequence(string str)
{      
    return (from Match match in Regex.Matches(str, "H+|T+")
            select match.Value.Length into matchLength
            orderby matchLength descending
            select matchLength).First();
}
```

or

```
public static int MaxSequence(string str)
{      
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, "H+|T+");
    return matches.Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(match => match.Value.Length)
                  .OrderByDescending(len => len)
                  .First();
}
```

In fact, you don't need to call `OrderByDescending` and then `First` here - you just want the maximal value, which the `Max` method gets you. Even better, it lets you specify a projection from a source element type to the value you're trying to find, so you can do without the `Select` too:

```
public static int MaxSequence(string str)
{      
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, "H+|T+");
    return matches.Cast<Match>()
                  .Max(match => match.Value.Length);
}
```

If you have a collection which has *some* elements of the right type but some which may not be, you can use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) instead. `Cast` throws an exception when it encounters an item of the "wrong" type; `OfType` just skips over it.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm not sure how I missed that method in the documentation, but that's exactly what I was looking for! Also thanks for the tip on using Max()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) or [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) on an `IEnumerable` to convert. `Cast` will throw illegal cast if the element cannot be cast to the stated type while `OfType` will skip any elements that cannot be converted.

Answer (score 0):

```
matches.Cast<Match>();
```